# Flux Backlog tasks not executed correctly in the event of an exception inspite of using FlatMapDelayError

Tags: java, spring-webflux, project-reactor

I am facing an issue where I have a Flux of data of which some of them can yield an error.I need to process the correct one's and finally yield an error for the incorrect data.I have the below sample code that is close to what I am doing.The expectation is that the code separates out the odd and the even integers into its own groups and further reduces them to a final value.However when it encounters "Zero" it is to throw an exception.So the final expectation is an exception for "Zero" and a reduced integer for both odd and even numbers.

```
public class Example1FlatMapDelayError1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ReactorDebugAgent.init();
        ReactorDebugAgent.processExistingClasses();

    Flux.just(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0)
        .flatMapDelayError(
            integer -> {
              if (integer == 0) {
                return Mono.error(() -> new IllegalStateException());
              }
              return Mono.just(integer);
            },
            4,
            3)
        .groupBy(integer -> integer % 2 == 0 ? "Even" : "Odd")
        .flatMapDelayError(
            group -> {
              System.out.println("Grouping Key-->" + group.key());

              return group
                  .collectList()
                  .doOnNext(integers -> {
                      System.out.println("Key Vlaue -->" + integers.stream().map(integer -> String.valueOf(integer)).collect(Collectors.joining(",")));
                  })
                  .flatMapMany(
                      integers -> {
                        return Flux.fromIterable(integers).reduce((i1, i2) -> i1 * i2);
                      });
            },
            4,
            3)
        .subscribe(
            out -> System.out.println("Final -> " + out), throwable -> throwable.printStackTrace());

       
    }
}
```

On the contrary the behaviour I see is that the entire flow breaks with a nested exception and none of the computations are done.Attaching the trace for reference.Appreciate help in understanding where I have gone wrong.

JDK :11
Reactor: 3.4.9

> SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings. ... SLF4J: Actual
> binding is of type
> [com.apple.jvm.commons.logging.structured.slf4j.MapHidingLog4jLoggerFactory]
> Grouping Key-->Odd Grouping Key-->Even
> reactor.core.Exceptions$CompositeException: Multiple exceptions   at
> reactor.core.Exceptions.multiple(Exceptions.java:120)     at
> reactor.core.Exceptions.addThrowable(Exceptions.java:92)  at
> reactor.core.publisher.FluxFlatMap$FlatMapMain.innerError(FluxFlatMap.java:858)
> at
> reactor.core.publisher.FluxFlatMap$FlatMapInner.onError(FluxFlatMap.java:990)
> at
> reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblySubscriber.onError(FluxOnAssembly.java:393)
> at
> reactor.core.publisher.FluxFlatMap$FlatMapMain.checkTerminated(FluxFlatMap.java:821)
> at
> reactor.core.publisher.FluxFlatMap$FlatMapMain.drainLoop(FluxFlatMap.java:608)
> at
> reactor.core.publisher.FluxFlatMap$FlatMapMain.drain(FluxFlatMap.java:588)
> at
> reactor.core.publisher.FluxFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onError(FluxFlatMap.java:451)
> at
> reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblySubscriber.onError(FluxOnAssembly.java:393)
> at
> reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblySubscriber.onError(FluxOnAssembly.java:393)
> at
> reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeekFuseable$PeekFuseableSubscriber.onError(FluxPeekFuseable.java:234)
> at
> reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblySubscriber.onError(FluxOnAssembly.java:393)
> at
> reactor.core.publisher.MonoCollectList$MonoCollectListSubscriber.onError(MonoCollectList.java:113)
> at
> reactor.core.publisher.FluxGroupBy$UnicastGroupedFlux.checkTerminated(FluxGroupBy.java:667)
> at
> reactor.core.publisher.FluxGroupBy$UnicastGroupedFlux.drainRegular(FluxGroupBy.java:559)
> at
> reactor.core.publisher.FluxGroupBy$UnicastGroupedFlux.drain(FluxGroupBy.java:652)
> at
> reactor.core.publisher.FluxGroupBy$UnicastGroupedFlux.onError(FluxGroupBy.java:702)
> at
> reactor.core.publisher.FluxGroupBy$GroupByMain.signalAsyncError(FluxGroupBy.java:266)
> at
> reactor.core.publisher.FluxGroupBy$GroupByMain.checkTerminated(FluxGroupBy.java:427)
> at
> reactor.core.publisher.FluxGroupBy$GroupByMain.drainLoop(FluxGroupBy.java:385)
> at
> reactor.core.publisher.FluxGroupBy$GroupByMain.drain(FluxGroupBy.java:329)
> at
> reactor.core.publisher.FluxGroupBy$GroupByMain.onError(FluxGroupBy.java:219)
> at
> reactor.core.publisher.FluxFlatMap$FlatMapMain.checkTerminated(FluxFlatMap.java:821)
> at
> reactor.core.publisher.FluxFlatMap$FlatMapMain.drainLoop(FluxFlatMap.java:608)
> at
> reactor.core.publisher.FluxFlatMap$FlatMapMain.drain(FluxFlatMap.java:588)
> at
> reactor.core.publisher.FluxFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onComplete(FluxFlatMap.java:465)
> at
> reactor.core.publisher.FluxArray$ArraySubscription.slowPath(FluxArray.java:138)
> at
> reactor.core.publisher.FluxArray$ArraySubscription.request(FluxArray.java:100)
> at
> reactor.core.publisher.FluxFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onSubscribe(FluxFlatMap.java:371)
> at reactor.core.publisher.FluxArray.subscribe(FluxArray.java:53)    at
> reactor.core.publisher.FluxArray.subscribe(FluxArray.java:59)     at
> reactor.core.publisher.Flux.subscribe(Flux.java:8411)     at
> reactor.core.publisher.Flux.subscribeWith(Flux.java:8584)     at
> reactor.core.publisher.Flux.subscribe(Flux.java:8381)     at
> reactor.core.publisher.Flux.subscribe(Flux.java:8305)     at
> reactor.core.publisher.Flux.subscribe(Flux.java:8275)     at
> com.apple.ist.empsys.amalgam.config.services.Example1FlatMapDelayError1.main(Unknown
> Source)   Suppressed: java.lang.IllegalStateException         at
> com.apple.ist.empsys.amalgam.config.services.Example1FlatMapDelayError1.lambda$main$0(Example1FlatMapDelayError1.java:22)
> Suppressed:
> reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblyException:  Assembly
> trace from producer [reactor.core.publisher.MonoCollectList] :
> reactor.core.publisher.GroupedFlux.collectList
> com.apple.ist.empsys.amalgam.config.services.Example1FlatMapDelayError1.lambda$main$7(Example1FlatMapDelayError1.java:35)
> Error has been observed at the following site(s):     |_
> GroupedFlux.collectList ⇢ at
> com.apple.ist.empsys.amalgam.config.services.Example1FlatMapDelayError1.lambda$main$7(Example1FlatMapDelayError1.java:35)
> |_           Mono.doOnNext ⇢ at
> com.apple.ist.empsys.amalgam.config.services.Example1FlatMapDelayError1.lambda$main$7(Example1FlatMapDelayError1.java:36)
> |_               Mono.flux ⇢ at
> com.apple.ist.empsys.amalgam.config.services.Example1FlatMapDelayError1.lambda$main$7(Example1FlatMapDelayError1.java:39)
> |_  Flux.flatMapDelayError ⇢ at
> com.apple.ist.empsys.amalgam.config.services.Example1FlatMapDelayError1.lambda$main$7(Example1FlatMapDelayError1.java:40)
> |_ GroupedFlux.collectList ⇢ at
> com.apple.ist.empsys.amalgam.config.services.Example1FlatMapDelayError1.lambda$main$7(Example1FlatMapDelayError1.java:35)
> |_           Mono.doOnNext ⇢ at
> com.apple.ist.empsys.amalgam.config.services.Example1FlatMapDelayError1.lambda$main$7(Example1FlatMapDelayError1.java:36)
> |_               Mono.flux ⇢ at
> com.apple.ist.empsys.amalgam.config.services.Example1FlatMapDelayError1.lambda$main$7(Example1FlatMapDelayError1.java:39)
> |_  Flux.flatMapDelayError ⇢ at
> com.apple.ist.empsys.amalgam.config.services.Example1FlatMapDelayError1.lambda$main$7(Example1FlatMapDelayError1.java:40)
> Stack trace:          at
> com.apple.ist.empsys.amalgam.config.services.Example1FlatMapDelayError1.lambda$main$0(Example1FlatMapDelayError1.java:22)
> at
> reactor.core.publisher.MonoErrorSupplied.call(MonoErrorSupplied.java:61)
> at
> reactor.core.publisher.FluxFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onNext(FluxFlatMap.java:405)
> at
> reactor.core.publisher.FluxArray$ArraySubscription.slowPath(FluxArray.java:127)
> at
> reactor.core.publisher.FluxArray$ArraySubscription.request(FluxArray.java:100)
> at
> reactor.core.publisher.FluxFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onSubscribe(FluxFlatMap.java:371)
> at reactor.core.publisher.FluxArray.subscribe(FluxArray.java:53)
> at reactor.core.publisher.FluxArray.subscribe(FluxArray.java:59)
> at reactor.core.publisher.Flux.subscribe(Flux.java:8411)            at
> reactor.core.publisher.Flux.subscribeWith(Flux.java:8584)             at
> reactor.core.publisher.Flux.subscribe(Flux.java:8381)             at
> reactor.core.publisher.Flux.subscribe(Flux.java:8305)             at
> reactor.core.publisher.Flux.subscribe(Flux.java:8275)             at
> com.apple.ist.empsys.amalgam.config.services.Example1FlatMapDelayError1.main(Unknown
> Source)   Suppressed: [CIRCULAR REFERENCE:
> java.lang.IllegalStateException]  Suppressed: [CIRCULAR REFERENCE:
> java.lang.IllegalStateException] Disconnected from the target VM,
> address: '127.0.0.1:51263', transport: 'socket'
>
> Process finished with exit code 0

Comment: Th doc says error is replaced if the mapper *throws* an exception. Can you try to throw directly an exception from the mapping function ? (I cannot test it myself for now)

Comment: @amanin Sorry for the delayed reply.I tried your suggestion replacing "Mono.error()" by throwing the exception, but the results are the same

Answer (score 0):

You have a cricular reference due to your reduce. You need to restructure you code to remove the reprocessing of exceptions.

```
public class Example1FlatMapDelayError1 {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    Flux<GroupedFlux<Object, Integer>> flux1 = Flux.just(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0)
      .flatMapDelayError(integer -> {
        if (integer == 5) {
          return Mono.error(() -> new IllegalStateException("5"));
        }
        return Mono.just(integer);
      }, 4, 3)
      .groupBy(integer -> integer % 2 == 0 ? "Even" : "Odd");

    Flux<Integer> flux2 = flux1.flatMapDelayError(group ->
      group.reduce(0, (i1, i2) -> i1 * i2), 4, 5); // Reduce processes exceptions multiple times...

    flux2.subscribe(x -> System.out.println("Final -> " + x), err -> err.printStackTrace());
  }
}
```